# Flask static path and multi level route

Tags: python, flask

So I a new to the whole web and Flask programming. I was moving along pretty good displaying information from my database in web pages then I mixed a little bit of java script in. But then because of what I have been reading on the internet I got the idea to organize my URLs like so

- localhost:5000/data/daily
- localhost:5000/data/weekly
- localhost:5000/data/monthly

However when I make my URLs more then one level deep when flask pulls up the page I end up getting java script errors because these extra levels have been append to my src attribute path in my script tags.

So what is going on here? Is there just some basic tid bit of web programming knowledge I am missing? I added some code bits below that shows example of what I am encountering.

The files below are in the following folder configuration

```
project_root
├── app.py
├── static
│   └── js
│       └── clock.js
└── templates
    ├── clock.html
    └── index.html
```

app.py

```
import flask

app = flask.Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/clock')
def clock():
    return flask.render_template('clock.html')

@app.route('/deep/clock')
def deep_clock():
    return flask.render_template('clock.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

clock.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="static/js/clock.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="startTime()">

<div id="txt"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

clock.js

```
function startTime() {
    var today = new Date();
    var h = today.getHours();
    var m = today.getMinutes();
    var s = today.getSeconds();
    m = checkTime(m);
    s = checkTime(s);
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML =
    h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
    var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
}
function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i};  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
    return i;
}
```

So if you copy everything and run the app.py then

- localhost:5000/deep/clock **will fail**

and

- localhost:5000/clock **works**

So what is going on here? What do I need to do to get them both to work in the current configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you run the app, you should see the log says:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Nov/2015 11:00:40] "GET /clock HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Nov/2015 11:00:40] "GET /static/js/clock.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Nov/2015 11:00:52] "GET /deep/clock HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Nov/2015 11:00:52] "GET /deep/static/js/clock.js HTTP/1.1" 404
```

---

As you can see, the **LAST** log says `404`(NOT FOUND): it can't find the `clock.js` under `/deep/static/js/`. That's true, we don't have that folder at all.

so, the problem is the js path. The solution is:

change your js path from:

```
<script src="static/js/clock.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script src={{ url_for('static', filename="js/clock.js") }}></script>
```

now, everything should be good now :) with the help of this one, we can find our file successfully.

---

The documentation: [Static Files](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#static-files)

Comment: OK thanks that does solve the problem but do you have more explanation as to what exactly is going on here? What do I need url_for. I have looked at the Flask docs and I don't understand why url_for is needed in the first place? Shouldn't everything reference relative to where the app.py is run from?

Comment: Just added more explanation and the documentation. Use `url_for` can help us find the right static files. Without it, as you can see, your program fails because of the wrong static file path. You can't just directly specify the js path, the relative reference won't work, not just so simple.

Comment: @mechsin - url_for is necessary because it grabs the path from the Flask configuration and avoids the need for adjusting your references in the HTML. Static files are hosted in the static folder just as templates are stored in the templates folder, but those can be changed. url_for is just a helpful method to help you find your resources.